# Cannot execute Synchronised thread

Tags: java, java-threads

I tried a code from Textbook about synchronized thread.
Tried writing the code as it is. But getting the error:

```
cannot find symbol f.start(); and t.display();
```

The textbook code was supposed to be tried without the synchronized keyword.
But it seems the compiler is unable to recognize the object.
Please help..

```java
class First 
{
    synchronized void display (String s)
    {
        System.out.println(s);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");  
        }
        System.out.println("***");
    }
}

class Second  implements Runnable 
{
    String s;
    First f;    
    Thread t;

    public Second(First f1,String s1)
    {
        f=f1;
        s=s1;
        t=new Thread(this);
        f.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        t.display(s);
    }
}

class SyncThread
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        First f=new First();
        Second ob1=new Second(f,"First");
        Second ob2=new Second(f,"Second");
        Second ob3=new Second(f,"Third");

        try
        {
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: f is First class instance not a Thread subclass instance or runnable interface subclass. Of couse, f cannot call start.  t is not First subclass instance of couse no display method.

Comment: Thank You everyone. It seems to be working after changes that you all suggested. Also I didn't knew that there is no display method in Thread class.But in my textbook it says- The run() method of Second class,calls the display() on instance of First. Is it a misprint???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread class does not have display method and your class First has the display method. I think you have wrongly typed t.display() and f.start(). Try to swith to f.display() and t.start().

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing

```
t = new Thread(this);
f.start();
```

try:

```
t = new Thread(this);
t.start();
```

and in the `run` method, try `f.display()` instead of `t.display()`

Looks like you're messing up some variables. Try using some meaningful names instead of `f` and `t`. It's more difficult to mess up `thread.start()` and `first.display()` than `t.start()` and `f.display()`.

Comment: Good showcase for correct variable naming, could not agree more.

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you an error possibly because you have not used the @Override annotation above 'run()' function.
Here is the revised code:

```
 @Override
public void run()
{
    f.display(s);
}
```

And Please do not run a thread in the constructor as it is not safe also you have made a mistake as it should be t.start() and not f.start(), similar changes in run()
should f.display(s) not t.display(s).

Changes:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    f.display(s);
}
```

And:

```
t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
```

Remember your variables because it would cause problems like these!
Now the program should run fine without any errors!